# "Maybe IRB bug!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

What exactly does this mean -- "Maybe IRB bug!"?  What does that tell me about the potential root cause of an exception?

[image]

Note that the text "Maybe IRB bug!!" was printed after the stack trace as part of the exception output.

Comment: Hmm, when I got this error (after a system stack too deep) it had one exclamation mark. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message means that IRB detected the cause of the stack trace being inside IRB's own code, not in the code you entered to be executed. And depending on what you did before that, it is thus likely that you triggered a bug in IRB.

A stack trace or segfault of a tool itself (as opposed to an error in user-code) is considered a bug almost all of the time. A tool should never die on user data, but always fail gracefully and with meaningful error messages. The one you see here is an attempt for one of those :)